# simple ansible command meets "ERROR: The file hosts is marked as executable"

Tags: ansible

new to ansible.

I installed ansible in ubuntu vm 14.04.1 version using ppa installation

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ansible --version
ansible 1.7
```

And created the `hosts` file with `localhost` only

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cat hosts
localhost
```

When I try to run this simple command

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ansible -i hosts all -m ping --ask-pass
SSH password:
ERROR: The file hosts is marked as executable, but failed to execute correctly. If this is not supposed to be an executable script, correct this with `chmod -x hosts`.
```

**UPDATE** when I follow the instruction to remove the execution mode for `hosts` file, it works.

But the message is still quite strange for me, why need execute `hosts` file.

What's wrong with this ?

Comment: It's saying the opposite - the file should not be executable, but currently is.

Comment: Oh,yes. But why? Will be good to provide as reason as answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few types of files that can be passed to ansible with the `-i` option.

1. Inventory files - [a single ini formated inventory file](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups)
2. A script that returns [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) as json
3. A directory that contains a combination of (1) and (2)

In your case Ansible assumed that because you had the executable bit set on the file *hosts* that it was a dynamic inventory executable.

It's very common to use a dynamic inventory file (2) for situations where you need to discover the ip addresses of the hosts that you want to work on. One example is the case where you need to query a directory service of some sort or maybe an API to get a list of hosts that are grouped on the fly.

Comment: I'm using ansible on files that are in a shared virtual machine folder where all files and directories are owned by root and marked as executable, is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: Other than making your inventory a script that outputs itself I don't believe there is a way around it.

Comment: Seems Ansible will not try to execute the inventory when the file-extension is `.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

For this nasty error message :

> ERROR: The file inventory is marked as executable, but failed to
>   execute correctly. If this is not supposed to be an executable script,
>   correct this with `chmod -x inventory`.

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/vfarcic/docker-swarm/issues/1)

In Vagrantfile, i added this :

```
srv.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', :mount_options => ["fmode=666"]
```